# Creating a drop-down menu in SQL in Access VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Currently in Access VBA I have a filter for a table "VolatilityOutput" in Access, as follows:

```vb
Dim CurveID As Long
CurveID = 15
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VolatilityOutput WHERE CurveID=" & CurveID & " AND MaxOfMarkAsofDate=#" & MaxOfMarkAsofDate & "# ORDER BY MaxOfMarkasOfDate, MaturityDate"
```

CurveID is a field in the table VolatilityOutput. Right now CurveID = 15 is hardcoded. Each Curve ID corresponds to a title in another field in table, CurveShortName.

So CurveID = 15  corresponds to CurveShortName = CAD Sovereign, CurveID = 124 corresponds to CurveShortName = CAD Swap New, and Curve ID = 134 corresponds to CurveShortName = CAD3M USD3M BASIS.

Instead of having CurveID = 15 hardcoded, I want to change it so that the user can select a CurveShortName from a drop-down menu, which applies the associated CurveID as a filter. Is this possible in Access?

**EDIT Update: The full code is posted here below:**

```vb
Public Sub CalculateVol()


Dim vol As Double
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim rs2 As Recordset
Dim iRow As Long, iField As Long
Dim strSQL As String
Dim CurveID As Long
Dim MarkRunID As Long
Dim MaxOfMarkAsofDate As Date
Dim userdate As String

DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM HolderTable"
'Clears out the old array from the holder table.

CurveID = 15

Dim I As Integer
Dim x As Date

userdate = InputBox("Please Enter the Date (mm/dd/yyyy)")

x = userdate

Dim BucketTermAmt As Long
BucketTermAmt = InputBox("Please Enter the Term Amount")

For I = 0 To 150

MaxOfMarkAsofDate = x - I


strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VolatilityOutput WHERE CurveID=" & CurveID & " AND MaxOfMarkAsofDate=#" & MaxOfMarkAsofDate & "# ORDER BY MaxOfMarkasOfDate, MaturityDate"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset, Options:=dbSeeChanges)
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("HolderTable")



If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then

    rs.MoveFirst

    rs.MoveLast


    Dim BucketTermUnit As String
    Dim BucketDate As Date
    Dim MarkAsOfDate As Date
    Dim InterpRate As Double


    Dim b As String

    b = BucketTermAmt

    BucketTermUnit = "m"
    BucketDate = DateAdd(BucketTermUnit, b, MaxOfMarkAsofDate)
    InterpRate = CurveInterpolateRecordset(rs, BucketDate)

    rs2.AddNew
    rs2("BucketDate") = BucketDate
    rs2("InterpRate") = InterpRate
    rs2.Update


End If

Next I


vol = EWMA(0.94)

Debug.Print vol


End Sub
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as "Excel"?

Comment: What do you do with `strSQL`?

Comment: Is this VBA working on a Form in some way?

Comment: I'll post the full code to make it clearer

Comment: You can't do what you want with only a query.  But if you put the dropdown on a form, a query can use the dropdown's selected value.  Is that satisfactory?

Comment: Sure that would be perfect. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do a few things.

1)  Add a new ComboBox to your form.  Call it cboCurve.  Set the Column Count = 2, and the Column Widths to be "0; 2" (without the quotes) and your Bound Column = 1.

2)  Add a new table, called tblCurve.  In this table you will have 2 fields; CurveID and CurveShortName.

3)  On Form_Load, add something like this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblCurve"
me.cboCurve.RecordSource = strSQL
```

(alternately, you can set tblCurve as the RecordSource right in the control itself)

4)  Add your values to the table.

5) Change the strSQL in your CalculateVol sub to be:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VolatilityOutput WHERE CurveID=" & Me.cboCurve.Value & " AND MaxOfMarkAsofDate=#" & MaxOfMarkAsofDate & "# ORDER BY MaxOfMarkasOfDate, MaturityDate"
```

Now, when you load the page your dropdown menu should populate with all the records from your tblCurve table.  All you'll see is the name and not the ID, because the ID field is the first field but you've set the width of the first field to 0 (making it invisible).  However, since you've bound your combo to column 1, that's what it will set as the value.  You then reference the value in your combo by using Me.cboCurve.Value.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I set it up as you mentioned, and set tblCurve as the RecordSource directly. However when I run the subroutine after changing strSQL, it tells me that this is an invalid use of the Me keyword. If I change it to Forms!cboCurve.Value, I get an application-defined error instead. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try taking out "Me.".  I've always had to add it, but I think newer versions of Access don't require it.  "Me." should equate to the current form, so I'm not sure why it thinks it's an invalid use.

Comment: I get a variable not defined error for cboCurve. I am doing this in a regular Module, is that the issue? Do I need to explicitly defined cboCurve or reference it in some other way?

Comment: That explains why it didn't like "Me.".  :o)  You have to do this in the module behind the form.  The Form_Load event of the form.

Comment: oh, ok. so do I have to move the CalculateVol subroutine to the module behind the form as well? I added a Private Sub Form_Load() as mentioned in step 3 to the module as well.

Comment: If I've already set the recordsource right in the control itself, what do I have to write in form_load()?

Comment: @varunchandra - It looks like you shouldn't have to do anything to the Load event of the Form.  Since CalculateVol is a public sub, you should be able to keep it where it is.  Have you added a break point to CalculateVol to make sure it's being called?

Comment: I think I might be confused on that point - I set the value that I want in the ComboBox on the form, then close it, and then I manually run the subroutine from the VBA tab. Should I be calling the subroutine somewhere? Sorry to ask so many questions and I appreciate the help very much.

Comment: Usually when you do this, you're running the code from a button on the same form.  Once you close the form, there's no way to know what the value you chose in the combo box is.  So, you need to leave the form open so the value can be read.

Comment: Perfect, I've finally got it working. Thank you again for your help.